# Maven 3.3.1 Config Error in IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-14

I got the maven .tar file from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi, and installed it to the path /usr/local/. I run the mvn -version command in the new window, the output is correct. Below is my .bash_profile in my home directory:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk7/Contents/Home  
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar  
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:  
export JAVA_HOME  
export CLASSPATH  
export PATH  
M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven  
M2=$M2_HOME/bin  
PATH=$M2:$PATH  
export M2_HOME    
export M2  
export PATH
```

and the mvn -version is below :

```
BianFranks-MacBook-Pro:~ Frank$ mvn -version  
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-    14T04:10:27+08:00)  
Maven home: /usr/local/maven  
Java version: 1.7.0_72, vendor: Oracle Corporation  
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk7/Contents/Home/jre  
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8  
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But the tips occurred when cleaning the module via Maven in Intellij IDEA 14:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk7/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/maven -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/maven/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/local/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.0.2 clean  
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check   $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.   
Process finished with exit code 1
```

the system property is not set, but I don't know how to set it...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Open up the IntelliJ settings dialog.

In Maven-->Runner options set a following VM option:
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=*project root*

Comment: Great, it's ok. Thx very much , But I wanna the reason why it occurred.

Comment: this case occurred because I changed my mac from air to pro, and the version of maven changed from 3.2.3 to 3.3.1.

Comment: It could be a bug in Maven 3.3.1 maybe?

Comment: yes, it's a known issue and fixed in nearest update :<https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783>

Comment: Can you please explain what "some_valid_path" represents here?

Comment: I'm sorry. "some_valid_path" is of course the Project Home directory

Comment: I set valid path to my maven home directory. That also worked.

Comment: @Frank, next time just answer the question, rather than leaving a comment. While dreamer gave an answer that is valid for maven 3.3.1 as a whole (there is a new required option), it wasn't actually the solution for IntelliJ users. Going to the issue you mention and downloading the various archives IS the solution. See avandeursen's answer for an example of how it's done.

Comment: What do you mean with runner options?

Comment: For me, it worked by putting $M2_HOME, i.e.

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME

Answer (score 20):

This is a [known bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783) (as indicated by @Frank) in IntelliJ 14.0.3 and 14.1.

It will be fixed in IntelliJ 14.0.5 and 14.1.1.

If you need the fix right now, you can download and install the specific fix as [described in the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783).

Alternatively, if you do not need the newest maven 3.3.1, you can fallback to an earlier version of maven.

Comment: I would like to say they bundled Maven 3.0.5 with the new Intellij 14.1 release which also could be a temporary fix for others.

Answer (score 16):

I've got the same error with these tools version:

1. apache-maven-3.3.1
2. Eclipse: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) with M2Eclipse 1.5.0
3. java: 1.8.0_31

Solved it by adding the VM argument (-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory= MAVEN_HOME_PATH)

Comment: Had the same problem with a similar setup. My only difference was using Mars Milestone 6. Apparently though, the argument doesn't even need a value, it just has to be there. Putting "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory= " into my VM args for the project solved the problem.

Comment: Works well also with Eclipse Luna

Answer (score 6):

If the variant from previous comments will not work:

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=project root

you can try this with quotes:

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=**"project root"**

This is exactly what helped me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. The one with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same with Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), following are the steps that i followed:

1. Goto - Run Configuration - under JRE tab - type -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=

This solution was provided by  sheltem Mar...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Run Configuration under JRE tab
2. type(in VM argument text field)
   "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory="

Answer (score 0):

This thread is important thread and very useful so I added this solution to it.
I added this line to maven runner and it works with me

```
    -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

Noting that, M2_HOME is defined in the environment variables for maven home in case of windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't rely on an external IDE, remember to put this in MAVEN_OPTS, like so (Linux)

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=<your path>
```

From Apache Maven's documentation, it's good to learn about this variable:

> This variable contains parameters used to start up the JVM running
>   Maven and can be used to supply additional options to globally to
>   Maven. E.g. JVM memory settings could be defined with the value
>   -Xms256m -Xmx512m.

You can refer to this link 
https://maven.apache.org/configure.html