# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match

Tags: maven

I tried to replace maven 3.1.1 with maven 3.3.1. After replacing all paths and M2_HOMe to new address, i have ran the build in my Idea IDE and got the subj message.

Unfortunately, can't get what is the problem of the build and why it is no longer working with new maven

Comment: as David said, that is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137172/maven3-3-1-config-error-in-intellij-idea-14

Comment: since I see too many people visiting this question instead of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137172/maven3-3-1-config-error-in-intellij-idea-14, I can just say that my question is more easy to find due to the error message the most people face with, but the actual problem description and the way how to fix it is clearly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137172/maven3-3-1-config-error-in-intellij-idea-14

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a know bug in IntelliJ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783

Just update Intellij and it will work :)