# Maven environment mac

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build something with maven, but keep getting the following error in intellij

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

So after searching the internet I found some ideas with the environment variables. But I checked with mvn -version and this is the response I get:

```
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
    Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
    Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

So I don't really know what I need to do extra to get this started?

Comment: Try pointing IDEA to your local Maven installation.  Hit `Ctrl+Alt+S` to bring up the settings, then search for `Maven` and then set the Maven home directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2\_HOME environment variable and mvn script match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153115/dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-set-check-m2-home-en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ, try to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983683/dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-not-set-issue-with-maven-and-intellij)

You need to set the argument `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME` to your JRE

Comment: pointing `$M2_HOME` to `jre` is bad idea. maven download dependency there. and `jre` folder most probably is readonly

Comment: I didn't say pointing $M2_HOME to the jre, I just said to add an argument (-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME) in the JRE settings of intellij