# Trouble building Vaadin application with Maven in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vaadin

I am looking to start a project using Vaadin and I want to use `Maven` as the `repository manager`, but I am having a lot of trouble starting the Maven project.

I tried creating a project in `IntelliJ` using the `vaadin-archetype-application-example` and it doesn't create any directory.

I also tried creating the project with the `mvn commands` and I found a lot of troubles too. When I create the Maven project this error is shown in the log:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

How can I deploy a `Maven` project with `IntelliJ`? I have the Maven plugin installed and the mvn command seems to work just fine.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.imtoolazytoadmin</groupId>
<artifactId>ImTooLazyToAdmin-master</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

Comment: Is it possible that this question is related: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137172/maven3-3-1-config-error-in-intellij-idea-14) ? Otherwise this could be your problem (fixed in newer intellij versions) : [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783)

Comment: **1)** What IJ & Maven versions are you using? **2)** Have you set the `M2_HOME` environmental variable? **3)** Please post the full log generated when manually running `mvn`.

Comment: I'm running IntelliJ 14.0 and Maven 3.3.3. Yes my M2_HOME is correctly set.

Comment: After adding  -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=project root in VM Option now IntelliJ displays the following log after importing the changes: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The defined artifact is not an archetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command to create your project and then import it to your IDE.

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
-DarchetypeVersion=7.5.9 \
-DgroupId=your.company \
-DartifactId=project-name \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-Dpackaging=war
```

More info about creating Vaadin projects in IntelliJ [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.idea.html).